# Android Studio Library Dependency - All Options are Alpha Versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

When I try to add a library to my Android Studio project they are all the latest alpha version instead of the current release version. It won't let me install non-alpha versions either via their direct name. [image: Screenshot of Android Studio Project Add Library Dependency]

Comment: You check it in the internet then paste on your build.gradle file :)

Comment: I don't understand. It's a setting in my build.gradle file that set this alpha choice?

Comment: no need to import library like that. please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your build.gradle file (Module:app) and you will see something like this

[image]

Then you can find name of that library like by type name of this library + "dependency" word in the Google, choose the version you want and paste it in this file like: `compile "your version you want"`

I think this page will helpful with you: http://mvnrepository.com/
.Type name of your library, choose version and select in Gradle format.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't fully answer my question. I want to add the library from inside Android Studio like the screenshot above shows.

Comment: Yes you can add it manually in the build.gradle.  However I came here after having to manually add it also and wondering how you can simply use the File > Project Structure... Modules app | Dependencies tab > + button >  Library Dependency without seeing the alpha only listings.  Is there a way or not get a listing that is not alpha? (Android Studio 1.5.1)

Comment: It would seem that Android Studio gives you the latest version, alpha included, at the time and if you want a specific version I think the above is the only way to do it. When I ran into trouble with this I checked on another system and the only offered libraries were also alpha. I'm curious as to what decides which libraries are displayed.